# Take screenshot of current html page using html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html2canvas

I'm building a chrome extension and it loads a list of images inside an iphone template img using bootstrap carousel.  So each iphone template has a different image.  The image is loaded by urls in the source attribute

Let's say the user picks an image and would like to have a screenshot of the image with iphone template included.  I added a button to download the image using `html2canvas`.

It downloads the screenshot but without the image, and I can't seem to figure it out why.  Is it because the `img src` attribute is an URL.

If so what other ways I can use to take a screenshot w/ or w/out html2canvas.

Here is my code

html

```
<div class="template-container">
  <img id="mobileImg" ng-show="link[2] == 255" src="../img/template_square_banner.jpg" alt="">
  <img id="mobileImg" ng-show="link[2] == 55" src="../img/template_rectangle_banner.png" alt="">

  <div ng-class="{squareLayer: link[2] == 255, rectangleLayer: link[2] == 55}">

    <img id="mobileAd" source="{{here it goes each url}}" width="{{ link[1] }}" height="{{ link[2] }}">


 </div>
</div>

<button id="saveTemplate" type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="downloadTemplate()">take screenshot</button>
```

javascript/angular

```
$scope.downloadTemplate = function(){

  html2canvas($(".template-container"), {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
  a.download = 'somefilename.jpg';
  a.click();

}
});
}
```

It would be awesome i can take a screenshot of the template, your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try using full path for images to see if it loads them or not?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban the full path is being added, for example the src will be "https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png".  It loads ok, but once it takes a screenshot, I see a blank spot where the image is supposed to be.

Comment: Is it from the same origin or not? html2canvas is sensitive about CORS, check their documentation to see how to allow that